# How to change the value of variable inside blade file and using script

Tags: php, laravel

Is it possible to change a value of variable using script? I'm trying to set the data I retrieved in my database and set it in a for loop but I don't know how and all I find are setting or changing value of Input field. I'm using modal so I'm retrieving and displaying it differently.

My code

```
 @php
 // value of retrieved in database should be in the variable $count
      $count = 3;
 @endphp
 counting....
 @for($i=1;$i<=$count;$i++)
      <br/>{{$i}}
 @endfor
     <br>The user have a total of {{$count}} children.
```

inside my script

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function (){
    $(document).on('click','.showBtn', function(){

      showModal();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/get_data/'+ id,
        success: function(response){
          console.log(response.count.number_of_children);
        }
      })
    });
  });
</script>
```

and in my Controller

```
public function get_data($id){
    $data = user::find($id);
    return response()->json([
        'count' => $data
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Do I understand this correctly? The user clicks a button (.showBtn) which executes an AJAX query to /get_data which returns a number (count.number_of_children), and you want to use this number to perform a PHP-loop that number of times? I see no way to achieve this and I think you had better implement that loop (and whatever it needs to do) in Javascript itself.